# Interrupting process in another thread

Tags: mbed

Will an interrupt defined in one thread interrupt any process in other threads? If not, how can this be done?

Specifically, I’m using mbed OS and timer interrupts (ticker).

Comment: So interrupts are hardware events that aren't defined in threads.  And in the operating systems that I know of, a thread is either contained in a process (Windows), or it is a "lightweight process" (Linux).  Can you clarify your question with the OS and hardware that you're working with, and maybe review what you're actually trying to say?

Comment: For single thread OS’s IRQ may  be prioritized, masked, non-masked, hardware or software generated where the stack must be  pushed with present tasks then branched to the IRQ vector to process to determine which interrupt occurred or next task. Then the stack popped to resume after IRQ tasks are done. SO yes a single tasking OS will always interrupt any other task when allowed.

Comment: You need to specify the operating system design and what you mean by "interrupt *defined* in one thread." If you are asking about what can happen when an interrupt occurs while running thread A, with regard to other threads as well as thread A, then we definitely need to know the operating system itself. In XINU, the interrupt takes place on thread A's stack, disables interrupts, but may reschedule things to start some other ready thread. Meanwhile, thread A has interrupts disabled but the new thread may have interrupts enabled. Context matters a lot here. You wrote two sentences. Write more.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts are a hardware feature, and the hardware is not, in general, aware of what thread is running at any given time as threads are a software construct.  Interrupts will interrupt whatever is currently happening on the CPU, unless they are disabled or masked, or a higher-priority interrupt is currently being handled.  Interrupts are really their own independent execution context; it is a job of whatever operating system you're running that manages the threads to connect the interrupts back to the appropriate thread, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupts can happen at any time, they are not tied to any thread.

Comment: As long as the operating system isn't mucking with the interrupts on a thread-by-thread basis.